# ¿«Todo está bien» or «está bien todo»?

Tags: sintaxis

Google translates «everything is fine» as «está bien todo». But should it not be «todo está bien»?

If both are correct, what’s the difference?

It translates past as «todo estuvo bien» and future as «todo estará bien».

Comment: Spanish often uses several word orders, and both can be right. The only difference is in emphasis.

Comment: Even when both are correct, the first option («está bien todo») is not at all frequent in Argentina (where I live). I don't recall finding it in any literature piece or TV/movie shows from other Spanish-speaking countries. Without any other given content, I would go with the second option. Of course, the first one could be a better choice within a more complex sentence.

Comment: @onpre Even in Argentina, if someone says to you: ¿Está todo bien? One can imagine the answer being: Si, todo está bien. It really has zero to do with where you live.

Answer (score 1):

"Todo está bien" y "Está bien todo"

Si bien "Todo está bien" muchas veces se utiliza como interjección, en "Está bien todo" "bien" como adverbio está modificando al adjetivo "todo", manifestando asentimiento o conformidad, expresando una forma acertada o dando la razón.

No obstante, en el habla coloquial se pueden escuchar ambas formas de manera indistinta. Así si vamos a un restaurante y nos preguntan ¿Está bien todo?, podemos responder "todo está bien". Por lo tanto en todo caso dependerá de los contextos donde se utilicen, aunque en principio su uso extendido puede ser indiscriminado.

Respecto al pasado y al futuro, las frases son correctas;

Pasado "todo estuvo bien" y Futuro "todo estará bien".

> Although "Todo está bien" is often used as an interjection, in "Está
> bien todo" "bien" as an adverb is modifying the adjective "todo",
> expressing assent or conformity, expressing a correct way or giving
> the reason.
>
> However, in colloquial speech both forms can be heard interchangeably.
> So if we go to a restaurant and they ask us, "¿Está bien todo?", we
> can answer "todo está bien". Therefore, in any case it will depend on
> the contexts where they are used, although in principle their
> widespread use may be indiscriminate.
>
> Regarding the past and the future, the sentences are correct;
>
> Past ""todo estuvo bien" and Future "todo estará bien".